# Updated Border Crossing Status Between Kosovo and Serbia

Tags: borders, serbia, kosovo

On my upcoming trip to the Balkans I'm looking to drive from Skopje, North Macedonia, to Tara National Park in Serbia via Pristina, Kosovo. As I plan to exit Kosovo directly into Serbia I would like to also cross into Kosovo from Serbia and, hence, am not planning on taking the most direct route (E 65). I want to cross into Serbia on the A-1, then pass through Presevo on the B35 and cross into Kosovo near Murcibabe. Does anyone know if that border crossing is currently open?

Comment: AFAIK the problematic direction is _from_ Kosovo _to_ Serbia -- you need a Serbian entry stamp first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this question later, I did the drive this summer and YES, the border crossing station between Serbia and Kosovo on the B35 between Presevo, Serbia and Murcibabe, Kosovo is open.